# How do I update the listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, startactivityforresult

There is  a `listView` in **WorkDetails**. When list is clicked, it will intent to **EditDetails**. When save button in **EditDetails** is clicked, it will return the updated value back to **WorkDetails**.

**EditDetails**

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     // if save button clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                project1=Project2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                description=Description.getText().toString();
                sqlcon.open();
                sqlcon.Update(ID, project1, description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("project1", project1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

**WorkDetails**

```
     ListView listViewUpdate;
     CustomBaseAdapter obj;
     ArrayList<DetailsBean> results = new ArrayList<DetailsBean>();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
     listViewUpdate = (ListView) edit_details.findViewById(R.id.listViewEdit);
     obj = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), results, listViewUpdate);
     listViewUpdate.setAdapter(obj);


           listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            mClickedPosition = position; // intent to EditDetils
                            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                            // Get the state's capital from this listview_item_row in the database.
                            ID =
                                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                            intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);


                        }
                    });

         public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("project");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");

                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.e("R",results+"");
                    Log.e("P",mClickedPosition+"");
                    results.get(mClickedPosition).setProject(ReceiveProject);
                    results.get(mClickedPosition).setDescription(ReceiveDescription);
                    obj.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

**CustomBaseAdpter**

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView

        private static ArrayList<DetailsBean> searchArrayList;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ListView listview;


        public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetailsBean> results,ListView listview) {
            searchArrayList = results;
            this.listview=listview;
             mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }


        public int getCount() {
            return searchArrayList.size();
        }


        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchArrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
```

**DetailsBean**

```
public class DetailsBean {

        private String project="";
        private String description="";

        public void setProject(String project){
            this.project=project;
        }

        public String getProject()
        {
            return project;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description=description;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

    }
```

> How can I refresh the WorkDetails listView so that it ables to show the
>   updated value return from EditDetails? When I click the list in WorkDetails, it shows the updated value.

**WorkDetails extends to Fragment and EditDetails extend to Activity.**

**LogCat error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails.onActivityResult(Edit_WorkDetails.java:123)
```

Comment: How is your `ListView` populated? What `Adapter` do you use? Usually, it is enough to add your new data to the backing array of your `Adapter` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `WorkDetails`'s listView's adapter and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `WorkDetails` or `CustomBaseAdapter` ?

Comment: @Knossos please check

Comment: @John just call `obj.notifyDataSetChanged()` since you called your Adapter obj

Comment: @Shark Are you happy to write the answer for me ? I still stucked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change onItemClick.

```
  listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
    int position, long id) {
        mClickedPosition = position; // intent to EditDetils
        DetailsBean detailsBean=results.get(position);

        // Get the state's capital from this listview_item_row in the database.
        ID =detailsBean.getID;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);


    }
});
```

Comment: In my case is `mClickedPosition` ?

Comment: app crashed..IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: You have results? why results = null?
results reference with searchArrayList. Where you get searchArrayList from ?

Comment: ya, results [] , mClickedPosition = 0

Comment: check results .size() =?

Answer (score 1):

- If you sure when `EditDetails` will update Data in `adapter` , use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onActivityResult`

Comment: I add this `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after  `ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");`, but no difference

Comment: You have update data of Adapter?. Please post  Adapter code

Comment: You add new DetailsBean in  changeItem ? it isn't change

Comment: You want change item in listView? or add new?

You can Log.e() in to:
if (obj != null) {
                        obj.changeItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

Log.e("Update listview","is update");
                    }

See log.

Comment: what should I do now,I want change

Comment: Please see new answer.I think this will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98874/discussion-between-john-and-quang-doan).

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
            protected void onRestart() {
                super.onRestart();
// call your adapter from here
                obj = new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), results, listViewUpdate);
                listViewUpdate.setAdapter(obj);
            }
```

**then set adapter from onRestart() again and check.**

Comment: write this method because everytime your listview loads it will automatically refreshed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98797/discussion-between-amit-vaghela-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Try following code -

```
public void changeItem(String Project,String Description)
{
    DetailsBean obj = new DetailsBean();
     obj.setProject("   "+Project);
     obj.setDescription("  "+" Work Description : " + " "+Description);
     searchArrayList.add(obj);
     add(obj);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```